# pydantic: how to type hint to mypy that a function accepts any model subclass

Tags: python, mypy, pydantic

Best asked through code:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Role(BaseModel):
    class Config:
        extra = Extra.forbid

    someprop: sometype = somedefault

class Administrator(Role):

    someprop = foo

class Teacher(Role):

    someprop = bar

...

def some_func_that_accepts_any_role(role: ?????)
    ...

a = Administrator()
some_func_that_accepts_any_role(a)
```

For `role: ???` I have tried both `Role` and `BaseModel`.

```
def some_func_that_accepts_any_role(role: Role)
def some_func_that_accepts_any_role(role: BaseModel)
```

However both leads mypy to complain with either

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Type[Administrator]", variable has type "Role")
```

or

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Type[Administrator]", variable has type "BaseModel")
```

what is the correct type hint to say "this expects a Role or any derived model"?

Really hoping I dont have to do:

```
def some_func_that_accepts_any_role(role: Union[Administrator, Teacher,..... (list all possible subclasses)])
```

EDIT: The answer was I needed `Type` although someone deleted that answer.

MRE that shows the error:

```
from typing import Type

from pydantic import BaseSettings



class Settings(BaseSettings):
    cache_clear: bool = False


class Staging(Settings):
    cache_clear = True


# WRONG (will run, but will not lint)
def print_settings(stn: Settings):
    print(stn().json())


print_settings(Staging)


# RIGHT
def print_settings_2(stn: Type[Settings]):
    print(stn().json())


print_settings_2(Staging)
```

Comment: If you provide and actual [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we could take a look at it and tell you what is wrong, but your code is not complete and not reproducible. The annotation `role: Role` is correct. It means an instance of `Role` or of any subclass of `Role` can be passed as the `role` argument. Not sure what you did to cause the error, but again, if you provide something reproducible, we'll see. Judging from your error message I would guess that you actually passed the class itself to the function, instead of an instance.

Comment: Good Q ^ Could benefit from tidying up the grammar + formatting.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg the answer that was deleted solved my issue. In both cases, the code *ran*. But I needed `Type[x]` which is what that answer said. I edited my question with an MRE.

Comment: I don't know about any deleted answer, I must have missed that. But that is **not** what you did in your initial code sample though. You were not passing the class to `some_func_that_accepts_any_role`, but an **instance** of `Administrator`. Please put some effort into your questions in the future, so that other people using the site can benefit from them as well.